# Getting Error: "Malformed entry 59 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list"

Tags: apt, 18.04, package-management, dependencies

I am getting this error:

```
an error occurred please run the package manager from the right click menu or apt-get in terminal to see what is wrong. The error message was;
Error:opening the cache(E:Malformed entry 59 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list(Component), E: the list of sources could not be read.)
This usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies.
```

Comment: Look at line 59 of that file, it was no doubt added by you or someone who has `sudo` rights on your box.  The line is invalid, or in wrong format, the result of which is that line & all subsequent lines are ignored.  You need to correct, comment out or remove that line.  We cannot really help further as we cannot see the line you have added.

Comment: What is the output of `sed -n '59p' /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/bionic main

Comment: okay so my problem has been solved now. i have corrected that line 59 by commenting it and it worked for me. thank you guys for helping me (: